# How to get NHibernate Configuration from ISessionFactory

Tags: nhibernate, configuration, fluent-nhibernate

Is there any way to get Configuration details from instance of ISessionFactory in NHibernate?

Comment: What configuration info are you looking for? The configuration object is not stored inside the session factory object, but a lot of the information in it is...

Comment: I wanted to have Configuration object to use it in SchemaExport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the ISessionFactory doesn't expose the configuration that was used to create the session factory, and I'm not sure the concrete implementation does either.

However, why don't you consider injecting the configuration to? Maybe you are not using dependency injection, if you do, just register it into the kernel.

Otherwise, consider using a wrapper class that keeps both the configuration and the ISessionFactory.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `app.config` or `hibernate.xml.cfg` I use the following to expose configuration:

```
NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration normalConfig = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration().Configure();
```

I pass the above in when I configure my session factory and I just expose this configuration object in my static session factory class.

Comment: No I need to get details of what Configuration used to build SessionFactory.

Comment: Well the above are the details of the configuration used to build the SessionFactory.  Are you fluently configuring all of your settings?

Comment: Yes fluently configuring. I'm injecting instance of SessionFactory to my client classes and wanted to do something based on Configurations I used to create SessionFactory.

Answer (score 1):

I have written an extension class that maps a session factory and configuration over a hashtable. And you can easily get a configuration for a session factory in any place of your code but you must set a configuration for a factory first.

```
public static class SessionFactoryConfigurationBindingExtension
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<ISessionFactory, Configuration> _mappings = new Dictionary<ISessionFactory, Configuration>();
    private static readonly Object _mappingsLocker = new Object();

    public static Configuration GetConfiguration(this ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        lock (_mappingsLocker)
        {
            if (_mappings.ContainsKey(sessionFactory))
            {
                return _mappings[sessionFactory];
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void SetConfiguration(this ISessionFactory sessionFactory, Configuration configuration)
    {
        lock (_mappingsLocker)
        {
            _mappings[sessionFactory] = configuration;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From Session I use the following 
`Session.Connection.ConnectionString;`

My class is 
`UserIO : Base<User>` 
User is entity.

Answer (score 0):

If you use dependency injenction:

```cs
public IServiceCollection ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add Configuration
    var configuration = BuildHNibernateConfiguration(_appSettings.connectionString);
    services.AddSingleton(configuration);
    // Add SessionFactory
    services.AddSingleton<ISessionFactory>(s => s.GetRequiredService<Configuration>().BuildSessionFactory());
    // Add Session
    services.AddScoped<ISession>(s => s.GetRequiredService<ISessionFactory>().WithOptions().Interceptor(new AppInterceptor(s)).OpenSession());
```

and then somewhere else:

```cs
var cfg = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<Configuration>();
```